# Primefaces responsive data table displaying sort drop down in all cases

Tags: sorting, drop-down-menu, primefaces, datatable

I am using a very basic example of responsive data table as follows:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{personManagedBean.personList}" var="person" reflow="true">
  <p:column sortBy="#{person.firstName}" headerText="First Name">
    #{person.firstName}
  </p:column>
  <p:column sortBy="#{person.lastName}" headerText="Last Name">
    #{person.lastName}
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The issue is that, once i make a column sortable by using the sortBy attribute, an extra drop down starts appearing on top of the data table for the respective column (as shown in the attached image).

I realize that this behavior is coming because i have made the data table responsive, but ideally it should appear only when the screen size is minimized enough that the responsiveness of the UI is active i.e. when the layout of data table's columns changes and becomes stacked. It should not appear in all cases.

Please suggest if there is a way to achieve the required behavior. Thanks.

[image]

**Environment:**

Primefaces version: 5.3.11

JSF version: 2.2

Browser: Firefox 45.0.2, Chrome 50.0.2661.94 m

Comment: This looks like something that should not happen. First check if it happens in a page with no custom css or other components ([mcve]. If it still happens, please create an issue in their issuelist. On solving your explicit issue, please check if something changes on the css of the combobox when actually minimizing the screen size so the columns become 'stacked'

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately the issue still persists even if i try it with bare minimum in an empty page with only p:dataTable component inside it.
Also, checked the css and no css changes noticed while squeezing the screen to and fro.

Comment: I have created an issue for Primefaces [here...](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1422)